# Conditional Formatting based on sum of other cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I have the following question. Let me have the following table consisting of total, A and B rows, each of them divided into certain years with certain values. I am trying to find a way that I could check for each year, if the value in year X(total) = the value in year X(A) + the value in year X(B). If the sum is the same, I want to colour the adjacent table cell green, or red otherwise. I have tried to achieve this with different formulas, but I have not been able to find something suitable for my case.

I'll be glad for help, I mention that I don't have much experience in excel

This is my excel table [image: my table photo]

What exactly do I want to get :

I add J16 + J25, if the sum is equal to the value in cell J7, then cell M7 should be colored in green, otherwise in red. And so on for the values of each year. I fully understand that it is possible to calculate separately for each value, but it is not an optimal method for me.

Comment: "I have tried to achieve this with different formulas" - then you should show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Conditional Formatting (VLOOKUP)

An easy way would be to select `M7:U7` and use the following formulas in *Conditional Formatting*:

**TRUE (Green)**

```
=VLOOKUP(M7,$I$7:$J$15,2,0)=VLOOKUP(M7,$I$16:$J$24,2,0)+VLOOKUP(M7,$I$25:$J$33,2,0)
```

**FALSE (Red)**

```
=VLOOKUP(M7,$I$7:$J$15,2,0)<>VLOOKUP(M7,$I$16:$J$24,2,0)+VLOOKUP(M7,$I$25:$J$33,2,0)
```

[image]

You can also use them in the sheet e.g. in `M9` as illustrated in the screenshot. That's an easy way to build such formulas.

Comment: I copied exactly what you wrote but I get the error "There s a problem with this formula"

Comment: The problem is that if your list separator is a semicolon (`;`), you need to replace the commas with it. Also, add the zeros as Mayukh Bhattacharya suggested. I'll fix it now.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir but why did you use the approximate match?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya When did you see me use it? I totally forgot about the 4th argument. Thanks.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I ran into such a problem: How can I use data from 2 colonies that are not neighbors. In my simplified example, I and J are neighbors, so I can use the consructia $I$7:$J$15, how do I proceed when I need column I and column K, for example ? the construct $I$7:$K$15 can no longer be used, because it will also contain the data of column J

Comment: Simply replace 2 with 3 i.e. of all the columns in `I:K`, `K` is the `3rd`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I don't think I understand you exactly

Comment: @VBasic2008 Or maybe you didn't understand me. I need ONLY column I and column K, without column J, so $I$7:$K$15 does not return the expected result.

Comment: It does if you use 3 instead of 2.

Comment: @VBasic2008 ahhh, I think I understand what you mean. I think that's it, right? 
=VLOOKUP(M7; $I$7:$K$15; 3; FALSE) = VLOOKUP(M7; $I$16:$K$24; 3; FALSE) + VLOOKUP(M7; $I$25:$K$33; 3; FALSE)

Comment: If you have MS365, you can use `=XLOOKUP(M7,$I$7:$I$15,$K$7:$K$15) = ...`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 is ok, the variant I wrote above works. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `XLOOKUP()` or `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX()`+`MATCH()`, here is what you can do in conditional formatting.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>M8</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(M7:U7,I16:I24,J16:J24,0)+XLOOKUP(M7:U7,I25:I33,J25:J33,0)
```

---

In Conditional Formatting Rules Manager:

• For Red:

```
=M8<>XLOOKUP(M7,$I$7:$I$15,$J$7:$J$15)
```

---

• For Green:

```
=M8=XLOOKUP(M7,$I$7:$I$15,$J$7:$J$15)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I used `OFFSET` and `MATCH` to get what you need.

```
=OFFSET($I$4,MATCH(M4,$M$4:$U$4,0)-1,1)
    =OFFSET($I$13,MATCH(M4,$M$4:$U$4,0)-1,1)
    +OFFSET($I$22,MATCH(M4,$M$4:$U$4,0)-1,1)
```

Use that in `M5` and extend across the range (or put it in the conditional formatting).

In R1C1 mode it is the same across all cells.

```
=OFFSET(R4C9,MATCH(R[-1]C,R4C13:R4C21,0)-1,1)
    =OFFSET(R13C9,MATCH(R[-1]C,R4C13:R4C21,0)-1,1)
    +OFFSET(R22C9,MATCH(R[-1]C,R4C13:R4C21,0)-1,1)
```

[image: Excel]